# Team vectors similar to word vectors for a corpus of text

Tags: machine-learning, word-embeddings, word2vec

Is there any way I could iteratively create a set of vectors, similar to vectors when embedding words through word2vec, that could represent vectors between teams, and also capture information about a point differential between teams? Or anything I should look into to possible find an approach to do this?

*As an example, say I have 3 teams, team A, team B, and team C.

- Team A beat team B by 30 points.
- Team B beat team C by 3 points.*

Could I create vectors for these teams that capture that team B and team C are nearly 10 times more similar than Team A is to either team.

I have attempted an approach using the python networkx library, where I created a network graph, used transitive closure to fill in unknown distances and then fit a multidimensional scaling transform on the shortest path found for each node pair.

However, this above approach produced vectors that did not capture these correct differences between teams. I think this approach may not have been able to capture the inherent deviation present in team scores seen in sports. Additionally, since this approach was not iterative I couldn't start with vectors from a previous year and train them as new game results come in.

As an aside, please let me know if I need to change formats, readn any documentation or alter this question/post in any way.
Thank you.

Comment: ["StarSpace: Embed All The Things!"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.03856) by 
Ledell Wu et al. might be a good start.